# Personalisation works on all pages except home

Tags: personalization

I have a basic component which uses Sitecore built in personalisation rules to switch an image.

The component works on every page of the site except the home page, where it always displays the default.

I’ve never come across this before. Does anyone have an idea what might cause this behaviour?

This is Sitecore 9.3.

Thanks

Comment: Specifically, which personalisation condition are you using?  Geo conditions, for instance, will not work on 1st request.

Comment: Do you have any separate Layout for the home page?

Comment: I’m using the Security > where the specific field in the user profile compares to value. It switches the image depending on if a user is a manager or not. 

It’s the same layout across the entire site.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have analytics disabled for your home item?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I’ve checked that already and analytics aren’t disabled. The strange this is if I restart the app service personalisation works for about 10 mins, then stops.

Comment: Are you caching your renderings that you are personalizing? Or any other caching that could get in the way?

Comment: There rendering isn’t cached. Plus the same rendering works on every page, accept home. It’s almost like analytics are disabled for the home page, but they aren’t.